# SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\tests\Variables.php on line 12

Tags: php

im learning php and im watching some lynda tutorials. i have installed wamp server and i get these errors:

> ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for ( ! ) Parse error: syntax
>   error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\tests\Variables.php on line 12

with this simple code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Basic</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
$var1 = 10;
echo $var1;
$my_variable = "hllo world";
$my_Variable = "Hello w0rld";
echo $my_Variable;
<br />
$var1 = 100;
echo $var1;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and i think im getting this because i have html tag in the php tag, when i remove the html tag from php and put it outside php tag it works...

Comment: Is there a question here?  You have identified the incorrect syntax and correctly guessed the reason why...  Though I'm not sure why you're getting the xdebug scream, there's no error suppression here...

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use html tags inside php tag, so just

```
echo('<br/>');
```

or split PHP tags like

```
?>
<br/>
<?php
```

Comment: Please adjust your second answer

Comment: You can mix your html code with php code (but for such construction I strongly recomend SMART), i.e. you can do sth like this: <?php $foo =10;?> <b>Text between php<b/> <?php echo $foo ?>

Comment: No, before you edited your answer, it was wrong, that is what i meant

Comment: but in the video tutorial the dude who was talking and showing his code he put html tags in the php and he didnt got any errors... and he clearly said that we can use html tags into php...